# In codeigniter controller fuction get all control name as column name

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my view

```
<form class = 'form_container left_label' id = 'addproduct_form1111', enctype = 'multipart/form-data' action="admin/product/UpdateProduct" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;" method="POST">
                 <input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="latitude" value="<?php echo $lat;?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="longitude" value="<?php echo $lang;?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="prdiii" id="prdiii" value="<?php if(!empty($product_details)){ echo trim(stripslashes($product_details->row()->id)); } else { echo "0";}?>" />
      <div id="tab1">
        <ul class="tab-areas1">
             <li>
            <div class="form_grid_12">
              <label class="field_title" for="user_id">Property Owner Name <span class="req">*</span></label>
              <div class="form_input">
              <?php 
              if(!empty($userdetails)){ echo '<select name="user_id" >';
                foreach($userdetails->result() as $user_details){


              ?>

              <option value="<?php echo $user_details->id;?>" <?php if(!empty($product_details)){ if($user_details->id==$product_details->row()->OwnerId){echo 'selected="selected"';} } ?>><?php echo ucfirst($user_details->firstname).' '.ucfirst($user_details->lastname);?></option>

             <?php  
                } echo '</select>';
             } ?>


              </div>
            </div>
          </li> 
          <li>
            <div class="form_grid_12">
              <label class="field_title" for="product_title">Title <span class="req">*</span></label>
              <div class="form_input">
              <?php if(!empty($product_details)){  $Valid = trim(stripslashes($product_details->row()->id)); } else {  $Valid=0;}?>
                <input name="product_title" id="product_title" type="text" tabindex="1" class="required large tipTop" title="Please enter the Property name" onchange="javascript:AdminDetailview(this,document.getElementById('prdiii').value,'title');"  onkeypress="return runScript(event);"  onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode!=13);"
                value="<?php if(!empty($product_details)){ echo trim(stripslashes($product_details->row()->product_title)); }?>"/>

              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="form_grid_12">
              <label class="field_title" for="price">Room Type</label>
              <div class="form_input">
                STANDARD  <br>


              </div>
            </div>
          </li>


         <li>
            <div class="form_grid_12">
              <label class="field_title" for="price">Price per day<span class="req">*</span></label>
              <div class="form_input">
                <input type="text" name="price" id="price" tabindex="9" class="required large tipTop" title="Please enter the property price" value="<?php if(!empty($product_details)){ echo trim(stripslashes($product_details->row()->price)); }?>"  onchange="javascript:PriceInsert(this.value,document.getElementById('prdiii').value,'price');"/>


              </div>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="form_grid_12">
              <label class="field_title" for="price1">Price per day for single occupacy<span class="req">*</span></label>
              <div class="form_input">
                <input type="text" name="st_price1" id="st_price1" tabindex="10" class="required large tipTop" title="Please enter the property price 1" value="<?php if(!empty($product_details)){ echo trim(stripslashes($product_details->row()->st_price1)); }?>"  onchange="javascript:PriceInsert(this.value,document.getElementById('prdiii').value,'st_price1');"/>


              </div>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="form_grid_12">
              <label class="field_title" for="price">Price per day for double occupacy<span class="req">*</span></label>
              <div class="form_input">
                <input type="text" name="st_price2" id="st_price2" tabindex="11" class="required large tipTop" title="Please enter the property price 2" value="<?php if(!empty($product_details)){ echo trim(stripslashes($product_details->row()->st_price2)); }?>"  onchange="javascript:PriceInsert(this.value,document.getElementById('prdiii').value,'st_price2');"/>


              </div>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="form_grid_12">
              <label class="field_title" for="price">Price per day for tripal occupacy<span class="req">*</span></label>
              <div class="form_input">
                <input type="text" name="st_price3" id="st_price3" tabindex="12" class="required large tipTop" title="Please enter the property price" value="<?php if(!empty($product_details)){ echo trim(stripslashes($product_details->row()->st_price3)); }?>"  onchange="javascript:PriceInsert(this.value,document.getElementById('prdiii').value,'st_price3');"/>


              </div>
            </div>
          </li>


          <li>
            <div class="form_grid_12">
              <label class="field_title" for="price">Room Type<span class="req">*</span></label>
              <div class="form_input">
                PREMIUM 
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>


        <li>
            <div class="form_grid_12">
              <label class="field_title" for="price">Price per day for single occupacy<span class="req">*</span></label>
              <div class="form_input">
                <input type="text" name="pr_price1" id="pr_price1" tabindex="13" class="required large tipTop" title="Please enter the property price 1" value="<?php if(!empty($product_details)){ echo trim(stripslashes($product_details->row()->pr_price1)); }?>"  onchange="javascript:PriceInsert(this.value,document.getElementById('prdiii').value,'pr_price1');"/>


              </div>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="form_grid_12">
              <label class="field_title" for="price">Price per day for double occupacy<span class="req">*</span></label>
              <div class="form_input">
                <input type="text" name="pr_price2" id="pr_price2" tabindex="14" class="required large tipTop" title="Please enter the property price 2" value="<?php if(!empty($product_details)){ echo trim(stripslashes($product_details->row()->pr_price2)); }?>"  onchange="javascript:PriceInsert(this.value,document.getElementById('prdiii').value,'pr_price2');"/>


              </div>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="form_grid_12">
              <label class="field_title" for="price">Price per day for tripal occupacy<span class="req">*</span></label>
              <div class="form_input">
                <input type="text" name="pr_price3" id="pr_price3" tabindex="15" class="required large tipTop" title="Please enter the property price" value="<?php if(!empty($product_details)){ echo trim(stripslashes($product_details->row()->pr_price3)); }?>"  onchange="javascript:PriceInsert(this.value,document.getElementById('prdiii').value,'pr_price3');"/>


              </div>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="form_grid_12">
              <label class="field_title" for="price">Room Type<span class="req">*</span></label>
              <div class="form_input">
                EXECUTIVE 
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>


        <li>
            <div class="form_grid_12">
              <label class="field_title" for="price1">Price per day for single occupacy<span class="req">*</span></label>
              <div class="form_input">
                <input type="text" name="ex_price1" id="ex_price1" tabindex="16" class="required large tipTop" title="Please enter the property price 1" value="<?php if(!empty($product_details)){ echo trim(stripslashes($product_details->row()->ex_price1)); }?>"  onchange="javascript:PriceInsert(this.value,document.getElementById('prdiii').value,'ex_price1');"/>


              </div>

               <input type="text" name="prsdfsdice" id="prdsfsdfice" />
                <input type="text" name="abc" id="abc" />
            </div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="form_grid_12">
              <label class="field_title" for="price">Price per day for double occupacy<span class="req">*</span></label>
              <div class="form_input">
                <input type="text" name="ex_price2" id="ex_price2" tabindex="17" class="required large tipTop" title="Please enter the property price 2" value="<?php if(!empty($product_details)){ echo trim(stripslashes($product_details->row()->ex_price2)); }?>"  onchange="javascript:PriceInsert(this.value,document.getElementById('prdiii').value,'ex_price2');"/>


              </div>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="form_grid_12">
              <label class="field_title" for="price">Price per day for tripal occupacy<span class="req">*</span></label>
              <div class="form_input">
                <input type="text" name="ex_price3" id="ex_price3" tabindex="18" class="required large tipTop" title="Please enter the property price" value="<?php if(!empty($product_details)){ echo trim(stripslashes($product_details->row()->ex_price3)); }?>"  onchange="javascript:PriceInsert(this.value,document.getElementById('prdiii').value,'ex_price3');"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>


           <li style="display:none">
            <div class="form_grid_12">
              <label class="field_title" for="description">Deal End Date</label>
              <div class="form_input">
                <input type="text" name="deal_end_date" id="deal_end_date" tabindex="9" class="required large tipTop datepicker" title="Please select deal end date" value="<?php if(!empty($ProductDealPrice)){ echo trim(stripslashes($ProductDealPrice->row()->deal_end_date)); }?>"  onchange="DealPriceInsert(this.value,'deal_end_date');"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>



          <li>
            <div class="form_grid_12">
              <div class="form_input">
                <input type="button" class="btn_small btn_blue nxtTab" id="nextImage" tabindex="9" value="Next"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </form>
```

This is controller

```
public function UpdateProduct(){ 
    /*image upload end */
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->input->post()); 

    $room_name = $this->input->post('room_name');
    $ame_name = $this->input->post('ame_name');
    //print_r($ame_name);
    //$r_val

    if ($this->checkLogin('A') == ''){
        redirect('admin');
    }else {

        $product_data=array();
        $facility_list=array();

        $product_id = $this->input->post('prdiii');

        if ($product_id == ''){
            $inputArr = array(

            );
        }else {
            $inputArr = array(

            );
        }

        $dataArr = array_merge($inputArr,$product_data,$facility_list);


        $condition = array('id' => $product_id);
        $this->product_model->commonInsertUpdate(PRODUCT,'update',$excludeArr,$dataArr,$condition);

        echo $this->db->last_query();die;

        $Attr_val_str = '';


        $this->setErrorMessage('success','Host added successfully');


        redirect('admin/product/display_product_list');
    }

}
```

This model Function

```
public function commonInsertUpdate($table='',$mode='',$excludeArr='',$dataArr='',$condition=''){
    $inputArr = array();
    foreach ($this->input->post() as $key => $val){
        if (!in_array($key, $excludeArr)){
            $inputArr[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
    $finalArr = array_merge($inputArr,$dataArr);

    if ($mode == 'insert'){
        return $this->db->insert($table,$finalArr);
    }else if ($mode == 'update'){
        $this->db->where($condition);
        return $this->db->update($table,$finalArr); 
    }
}
```

I dont know how controller fuction get all form controls name as column and send to model function. Please Help.

Error: This is code that model fuction get all control name but i dont need all i need some specifc column.

```
UPDATE `fc_product` SET `latitude` = '28.44886970520019500', `longitude` = '77.09976959228516000', `prdiii` = '9', `user_id` = '38', `product_title` = 'STARiHOTELS Guragaon', `price` = '25000.00', `st_price1` = '0.00', `st_price2` = '0.00', `st_price3` = '0.00', `pr_price1` = '25000.00', `pr_price2` = '35000.00', `pr_price3` = '40000.00', `ex_price1` = '0.00', `prsdfsdice` = '', `abc` = '', `ex_price2` = '0.00', `ex_price3` = '0.00', `deal_amount` = '', `deal_start_date` = '', `deal_end_date` = '', `status` = 'on', `meta_title` = '', `meta_keyword` = 'ghhj', `meta_description` = ' hjghghj', `userID` = '0' WHERE `id` = '9'
```

Comment: to do that set all input name same as DB cloumn name directly....fast and easy!!No need to code separately for that

Comment: It is required as there is some data to save another table not this. and want reason how it get all control name??